# I want to design a page to save pictures But I have a problem with the fatal error LNK1168

Tags: flutter, dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SavedPostsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
final List savedPosts = [
'assets/images/p1.jpg',
'assets/images/p2.jpg',
'assets/images/p3.jpg',

```
// قائمة المحفوظات الخاصة بك
```

];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text('المحفوظات'),
backgroundColor: Colors.green,
actions: [
IconButton(
icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
onPressed: () {

```
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: GridView.builder(
    itemCount: savedPosts.length,
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 3, 
      mainAxisSpacing: 8.0, 
      crossAxisSpacing: 8.0, 
    ),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Image.asset(
      

        savedPosts[index],
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

}
}

I want to design a page to save pictures

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).